# Deploying RC2 NETCore app to Azure AppService

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, publish

I've tried deploying an RC2 webapp to Azure using the following version: **1.0.0-rc2-20222**.

**Publishing**

1. I packaged everything with

> dotnet publish -c "Release" -o "./approot"

next step was to copy over the "**approot**" and "**wwwroot**" folders manually to the /site directory via Azure FTP.

**Running**

Unfortunately i receive the following error:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

I am not using the free tier.

Does anybody have a solution to that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also looking for a solution, as I have the same issue.